# Unable to merge dex :app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.

Tags: java, android-studio

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex